# Want to add cart and a search bar in the right of logo line

Tags: theme-development, woocommerce-offtopic, static-website

Hi actually in the theme there is a system to keep cart and search bar on the menu.But i want in the right of logo.
How can i add this?please help me.
My site link--http://girlesse.virtumultimedia.com/
[image]

Answer (score 1):

its an unclear question,

You didn't specify which theme you are using?

but i guess if you explore the theme settings you would have the alternative header styles, as most of the latest themes have different type of header styles

with the above mention description, that what i can suggest you.

Comment: hi dear please check my site--http://girlesse.virtumultimedia.com/  Using creativo theme

Comment: check out your theme demos, it seems like they do have other header styles within Theme's settings.